# 429 status code if I make call outs in Batch execute

Tags: batch, integration, callout

From a batch apex I am trying a make a call out in for loop as like below

```
for(eBilling__c bill : lstBilling){ 
             try {   
                HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();      
                req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
                req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + PowerOfficeRecord.Access_token__c);
                req.setEndpoint(creds.URL__c);
                req.setMethod('POST');
                List<OutgoingInvoiceLine> outGoingInvoice= new List<OutgoingInvoiceLine>();

                for(eBilling_Line__c billingLine: bill.eBilling_Lines__r){
                    outGoingInvoice.add(new OutgoingInvoiceLine(billingLine.Product__r.Name,billingLine.Quantity__c, String.Valueof(billingLine.Product__c),billingLine.Unit_Price__c));
                }

                try{
                    string strPayLoad=genPayload(bill.name,Date.valueof(bill.Billing_Date__c),bill.CurrencyIsoCode, Integer.valueof(bill.Account__r.Customer_Code_for_Power_office__c),outGoingInvoice);
                    req.setBody(strPayLoad);
                    System.HttpResponse res = new System.Http().send(req);

                    if (res != null &&  res.getStatusCode() != 200 ){
                        HandleLogs.LogAPIInformationIntoObject('PostInvoiceToPowerOfficeBatch', 'execute', strPayLoad,res.getBody(), creds.URL__c, String.Valueof(res.getStatusCode()),'Power Offfice');
                    }   
                }
                catch(Exception Ex){
                    HandleLogs.LogErrorIntoObject('PostInvoiceToPowerOfficeBatch', 'execute', 'Input Parameters are :: {0}' + bill.Id , Ex);                
                }}
                catch (Exception Ex) {         
                    HandleLogs.LogErrorIntoObject('PostInvoiceToPowerOfficeBatch', 'execute', 'Input Parameters are :: {0}' + bill.Id , ex);    
                }
        }
```

since I am calling in for loop I am getting 429 too many request error from server. How to overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HTTP 429](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429) means that the remote server is rate-limiting you. The solution is very specific to the server you are calling, so you should discuss this issue with your support team or the vendor of the remote server.

The remote server may, but is not required to, include a `Retry-After` header to tell you when you can try again. Depending on the ownership of the remote server and the extent to which its owner is willing to work with you, you may need to either refactor your code to reduce request volume, use scheduling to retry, or, best of all, have your client allow-listed to increase your rate limit.